# How to reduce code for multiple JUnit assertions?

Tags: java, junit, refactoring, tdd, testng

I've got a *massive* (300 lines) test method that is formed by *assertEquals*, i.e:

```
assertEquals(tmParamResult.get(TagmanConstants.COUNTRY), COUNTRY_UK);
assertEquals(tmParamResult.get(TagmanConstants.STATE), EMPTY_STRING);
assertEquals(tmParamResult.get(TagmanConstants.LOYALTY_CARD), String.valueOf(false));
assertEquals(tmParamResult.get(TagmanConstants.REGISTERED), String.valueOf(false));
assertEquals(tmParamResult.get(TagmanConstants.REG_USER_ID), EMPTY_STRING);
assertEquals(tmParamResult.get(TagmanConstants.REG_DATE), EMPTY_STRING);
assertEquals(tmParamResult.get(TagmanConstants.REG_DAY), EMPTY_STRING);
assertEquals(tmParamResult.get(TagmanConstants.REG_MONTH), EMPTY_STRING);
assertEquals(tmParamResult.get(TagmanConstants.REG_YEAR), EMPTY_STRING);
assertEquals(tmParamResult.get(TagmanConstants.SMS_SERVICE), String.valueOf(false));
assertEquals(tmParamResult.get(TagmanConstants.IS_INT), String.valueOf(false));
```

is there any way to refactor this? (Reflection, maybe?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can put the constants in an array or list and loop trough it.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. These are codes for test and they are clear.

Comment: What are those values? Default values? What is the purpose of the test mehod? What is your goal with refactoring this? It's already one-line-per-test, you're unlikely to make it smaller. And if you used reflection, wouldn't that rather defeat the purpose of the test, as you'd be using the code itself to test the code itself?

Comment: @grape_mao I really think is neccesary. We're talking about more than 300 lines of assertEquals.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sometimes default values, sometimes not. The purpose is clear, in my opinion, by seeing it, just checking if the expected value for a variable is the same we've got. Don't think reflection will "defeat" it, it will only make the code more clear.

Comment: @stackman It seems to me you are testing value of each key, and I'd rather have one line for each value so in IDE I can click to see error occurs on which line.

Comment: @grape_mao sorry I don't get the point you're explaining, could you please be clearer?

Comment: @stackman: If they aren't always default values, then how do you expect to get the value to compare with via reflection? And no, if the purpose of the test method were clear from reading it, I wouldn't have asked you want it was meant to do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If I knew it, I wouldn't post a question here, don't you think?  Regarding of your second question, I think the meaning of "assertEquals" is clear as day :-)

Comment: @stackman Does tmParamResult.get() is this method always accepts String and u r expecting String output ?

Comment: @stackman: Yes, it is. What **isn't** clear is what that sequence of `assertEquals` is meant to test. Why is it so hard to just answer the question?

Comment: @stackman Updated my answer

Comment: @stackman Well, it's not important...I mean we may find a way to test them with a generic method, but then it's harder to see which key has error, because error will occurs on the generic method. And you'll need to initialize a collection to hold the values which is complicated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you model has many fields to check, indeed, you have not the choice you should check each field value.

Now, the way you handle that is maybe not the most suitable solution since if you want to do equals assertion with a `tmParamResult` instance for another test case, you should rewrite all `Assert.assert(...)` for each field.
You could create a private method which takes as parameter the expected and the actual `tmParamResult`. In this way, for each scenario, you only need to create  another expected instance with probably some predefined values for some scenarios.

`tmParamResult`  is probably a Map but I prefer not guessing.

```
@Test
public void assertTmParamResultEquals(TmParamResult tmParamResultActual,TmParamResult tmParamResultExpected){
  assertEquals( 
  tmParamResultExpected.get(TagmanConstants.COUNTRY),
  tmParamResultActual.get(TagmanConstants.COUNTRY)
  ....
 )
```

---

**UPDATE** 
If you use Map object, you could use unitils library to perform assertion based on reflection. 
Here you could find more information : http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-reflectionassert.html

Maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
    <artifactId>unitils-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

It allows to perform reflection assertion even on map.

Here is a simple example :

```
@Test
public void assertMap() throws Exception {
  Map<String, String> expectedMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
  expectedMap.put("a", "1");
  expectedMap.put("b", "2");

  Map<String, String> actualMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
  actualMap.put("b", "2");
  actualMap.put("a", "1");

  ReflectionAssert.assertReflectionEquals(expectedMap, actualMap, ReflectionComparatorMode.LENIENT_ORDER);

}
```

With the first proposition, you could give do the assertion in this way :

```
@Test
public void assertTmParamResultEquals(TmParamResult tmParamResultActual,TmParamResult tmParamResultExpected){
  ReflectionAssert.assertReflectionEquals(tmParamResultExpected, tmParamResultActual, ReflectionComparatorMode.LENIENT_ORDER);
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Having such a large test method is to me an indication that the class or method under test is doing too much. Break that apart and the test method becomes simpler.